# Subset duplicate values with two different status values

Tags: r, subset

I have Id Values some are duplicates, there is another column Status (yes/No) , I want to extract the subset of duplicate values which have two different status values. For example , if my dataset is as below

```
   Id        Status
   23984     Yes
   94949     No
   89685     No
   33232     Yes
   33232     Yes
   57943     No
   75633     Yes
   75633     No
```

In this case, Id  75633 is duplicate and has two different status (Yes & No) so my final dataset should contain only such ids and not 33232.

```
   Id        Status
   75633     Yes
   75633     No
```

I know how to do a subset but no clue how to include this criteria need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    filter("Yes"%in% Status & "No"  %in% Status)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove all duplicate rows, than any ID that occurs more than once must have multiple statuses associated with it. So if your data frame is `df`:

```
tb <- table(unique(df)$Id)
names(tb[tb>1])
```

Or in one pipeline with magrittr:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% unique %$% Id %>% table %>% subset(. > 1) %>% names
```

Then you can subset the data frame to select only those IDs.

Answer (score 1):

What about this using tapply?

```
ind <- which(tapply(df$Status, df$Id, function(x) "Yes" %in% x & "No" %in% x))
df[df$Id == names(ind),]
     Id Status
7 75633    Yes
8 75633     No
```